# How to use PhoneGap with Android Studio 0.5.4?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

Can anybody tell me how get Android Studio 0.5.x to properly import and build a PhoneGap project ?

I've **successfully** installed the JDK SE 1.8.0, Ant 1.9.3, PhoneGap 3.4.0 and Android Studio 0.5.4.

`JAVA_HOME`, `ANT_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` are properly set, `PATH` was extended to include the `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` as well as `%ANDROID_HOME%\tools` and `%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools`.

I can create a PhoneGap hello-world project as outlined here:
http://phonegap.com/install/

The **vanilla** hello-world project as is will **build and run** with the configured AVD:

```
phonegap run android --emulator
```

However, when I try to import the project according to [this tutorial](http://code-aspdotnet.blogspot.ca/2014/01/developing-android-application-with.html) into Android Studio **0.5.4**, it won't compile.

First, import in 0.5.4 is **entirely different** from what is shown on the linked page, there are none of the presented options (you can only select the folder from which to import, the destination directory, and whether to "Replace jars with dependencies, when possible" / "Replace library sources with dependencies, when possible" and "Create Gradle-style (camelCase) module names", all selected by default).

Android Studio shows errors such as these:

```
Error:(19, 26) error: package android.annotation does not exist
Error:(26, 16) error: package org.json does not exist
Error:(30, 23) error: package android.content does not exist
```

However, I do see `< Android API 19 Platform >` and `< JDK >` in the *External Libraries* section, with `android.jar` and `annotations.jar` and e.g. `android.annotation` in there.

I tried to set `minSdkVersion 19` for project `helloWorld` but this didn't fix anything.

Comment: Try this http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/05/16/phonegap-android-studio/   http://bnotezz.tumblr.com/post/58250519240/create-phonegap-project-in-android-studio

Comment: The first link looks like the page I linked to, with the same dialogs that I am **not** seeing at all. The second link is scarce on details, it just says that one should import and it's done. Well, I tried, and the project was imported but did **not** compile. That is the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem with cordova 3.5.0 Would be great if someone can help out.

Comment: Although I've managed to solve the compilation errors, debugging is still a bit cumbersome. If you don't need PhoneGap's/Cordova's hardware support it's perhaps easier to just build an app with a WebView and use that. It might even be easier to add some bindings oneself if you don't need too many.

Comment: @Archimedix How did you solve the compilation errors?

Comment: Yeah, did you manage to get it running? I've got the same story here :)

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this same issue, except it's been with Cordova rather than PhoneGap. I'm unaware of what needs changing in the Android project to have it work in Android Studio (or Eclipse - found issues with both).

Instead I started to play around with versions. It looks like the error that occurs with Cordova version 3.5.0-0.2.4 doesn't occur with Cordova version 3.0.0. It's now building and running fine for me.

Getting an older Cordova version is simple, if on Mac OS X/*nix:

```
sudo npm install -g cordova@3.0.0
```

I suspect there is some sort of bug/inconsistency with the later Cordova versions. Note I chose v3.0.0 simply because I wasn't able to do the above for v3.1+.

If I get more time later on, I'll try analyse the differences between the 3.0.0 build and the 3.5.0 build.